# determine the home page in hooking wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

How can I determine in the wordpress hooking if the page is homepage?

for example in my _functions.php

```
function hook_premiumpress_page_before(){
 if (homepage){
   echo "<h1>This is Home Page</h1>";
 }
}
```

I don't know the syntax code about it.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// static page home
if(is_front_page()) {
  echo "<h1>This is Home Page</h1>";
}

// blogroll home page
if(is_home()) {
  echo "<h1>This is Home Page</h1>";
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/is_front_page
http://codex.wordpress.org/is_home

Also you could make a `front-page.php` or a `home.php`
[Template logic](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview)